# Запятая в конструкции "есть чем" при инверсии

Tags: пунктуация

Обычно конструкции типа "есть чем" и т. п. не разбиваются запятой. Но сохраняется ли это правило при нарушении порядка слов?

Имеем такое четверостишие:
*Есть землякам **(?)** чем с миром поделиться,

Делами их гордимся мы вполне!

Запечатлеем думы их и лица,

Их негасимый подвиг на Земле.*

Нужна ли в первой строке запятая?

Comment: Справочная служба Грамоты.ру ответила, что постановка запятой в данном примере уместна. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: "Справка" в своем репертуаре ))) А чем мотивировали хоть?!

Comment: Это всё, что они ответили, объяснений не последовало.

Answer (score 1):

Про "есть чем" сформулировано в ответе Справки:

> [Вопрос № 292148](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20292148)
>
> Здравствуйте. Нужна ли запятая в таких конструкциях? 1. Он нашел, чем
>   блеснуть перед журналистами. 2. Они нашли, чем похвастаться. 3. Она
>   нашла, чем поделиться с читателями.
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Запятая не нужна. Запятая в подобного рода конструкциях, состоящих из
>   глагола *быть, найти, остаться*, вопросительно-относительного
>   местоимения или наречия (*кто, что, где, куда* и др.) и неопределенной
>   формы другого глагола, не ставится, ср.: *будет о чем поговорить, есть
>   на что посмотреть, есть к чему стремиться, не нашла что сказать,
>   осталось на что жить и т. д.*

А про отмену запятых при инверсии - готовьтесь, многа букафф:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[В разговорной речи встречаются сложноподчиненные предложения с главной частью внутри придаточной: *Без него не знаю что бы делал; Прошло не помню сколько времени; Он не скажу чтобы был симпатичен; Так мы про бежали не считал сколько километров*.](https://www.rulit.me/books/spravochnik-po-russkomu-yazyku-punktuaciya-read-17921-70.html)